# how to hide titleBar in list?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

By the default list does not have titleBar, but when I create a list in such a way it has an empty titleBar

```
Ext.define('Application.view.RecipeList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'recipelist',
    requires: ['Application.store.Recipes'],
    id:'list',   
    config: {             
        grouped: true,
        itemTpl: '{title}',
        store: 'Recipes',
        onItemDisclosure: true
    }
});
```

Can somebody help me to understand how to hide titleBar?

Comment: Is it really all you have in your app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty bar is actually your navigation bar.

If you want to hide it you just need to set the `navigationBar` to `false` in your `mainpanel`

**Update**

```
config: {
    navigationBar: false, 
    items: [{
        xtype: 'recipelist',
    }]
}
```

**Update**

Here's how to add the searchbar in your navigationbar

```
this.getMain().getNavigationBar().add({
    xtype: 'searchfield',
    itemId:'contact_search',
    placeHolder: 'Search....',
    listeners: {
        scope: this,
        clearicontap: this.onSearchClearIconTap,
        keyup: this.onSearchKeyUp
    }
});
```

But then you need to hide it when you switch to the detail card, but I'll let you figure out how to do that.

Comment: the same result http://www.senchafiddle.com/#4hKD8#uZlr7#JywGI#3D6PK#DOaF9#NcOoQ#FduGS

Comment: See my updated answer. But then you don't have your navigationbar anymore, so you won't be able to come back from the detail panel then. So, I suggest you put your searchbar and put a searchfield within the navigation bar instead.

Comment: I also thought about it, but I add a search field in the controller main.js, is it possible to add it to navigation view?